# Normalize column fill with space on right

Tags: perl, awk, sed

Working with the example log file below:

```
1;000117;20190529;055529;9521;0988388019
1;000015;20190529;071944;2222;2231
1;000012;20190529;072734;4258;4252
1;000006;20190529;073336;2226;1000
3;000005;20190529;073715;1000;037760967
3;000004;20190529;073751;1000;037760967
```

I need to normalize the last column filling with spaces until they has the lenght = 25

Tryed with unsuccessful perl code:

```
perl -F';' -lane '$F[5] = $F[5], sprintf "% 25d"; $" = ";"; print "@F"'
```

I need the output below:

```
1;000117;20190529;055529;9521;0988388019               
1;000015;20190529;071944;2222;2231                     
1;000012;20190529;072734;4258;4252                     
1;000006;20190529;073336;2226;1000                     
3;000005;20190529;073715;1000;037760967                
3;000004;20190529;073751;1000;037760967
```

Comment: Try this: `perl -F';' -lane '$F[5] = sprintf "%-25d", $F[5]; $" = ";"; print "@F"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$NF=sprintf("%-25s",$NF)}1' file
1;000117;20190529;055529;9521;0988388019
1;000015;20190529;071944;2222;2231
1;000012;20190529;072734;4258;4252
1;000006;20190529;073336;2226;1000
3;000005;20190529;073715;1000;037760967
3;000004;20190529;073751;1000;037760967
```

So you can see the blanks:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$NF=sprintf("%-25s",$NF)}1' file | tr ' ' '#'
1;000117;20190529;055529;9521;0988388019###############
1;000015;20190529;071944;2222;2231#####################
1;000012;20190529;072734;4258;4252#####################
1;000006;20190529;073336;2226;1000#####################
3;000005;20190529;073715;1000;037760967################
3;000004;20190529;073751;1000;037760967################
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. More successful Perl codes:

```
perl -F';' -lane '$F[5]=sprintf("%-25s",$F[5]);print join ";",@F'
perl -F';' -pane '$F[5]=sprintf("%-25s",$F[5]);$_=join ";",@F'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i ':a;/;[^;]\{25\}$/!s/$/ /;ta' file
```

If the last field is not 25 characters long, add a space until it is.